# How do I write a formula looking for values to the RIGHT of a ","

Tags: formula

How do I write a formula looking for values in a separate field to the RIGHT of a comma.

So if I have field A that lists out "Red, White, Blue"

How do I write a formula in field B that returns "Blue"

I've written the below formula but it gives me everything after the first comma - so in this case  "White, Blue" - when all I need is Blue

`TRIM(RIGHT(Text_field__c, LEN(Text_field__c)-FIND(",",Text_Field__c)))`

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? In general, the first place to look for questions like this should be [the official documentation on Formula Fields and Operators](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5).

Comment: Hi Derek - I updated the question to include what I've tried and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
RIGHT(text_field__c, FIND(",", REVERSE(Text_Field__c)) - 1)
```

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much.